# Extjs 6.5 Highlight line series on legend mouseover

Tags: extjs, charts

I have updated from EXTJS 5.0 charts to EXTJS 6.5 Cartesian charts, and I noticed that one of the features from version 5.0-- the line series to be highlighted on mouse over the legend or the series itself--dosen't work in version 6.5. Please let me know how do we do that .

Example : 
Go to [this](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/examples/charts-kitchensink/#marked-line) link below and hover on one of the legends or lines

Regards,
Jason

Answer (score 0):

Rename tip to tooltip and you're good to go?
Here's the corresponding example from 6.5.1
http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/examples/kitchensink/?classic#line-marked